# What is the density size for iPhone 6+ in scaled mode

Tags: ios, retina

The retina display seems to be "high" in that resolution which is the equivalent of x2, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale factor is always 3 when the app is running in an iPhone 6+. But for an app that's not updated for that screen size, everything will be 2x hence everything will be automatically scaled up.

Comment: Right got you - so @x2?

Comment: Yes, since only old apps will be running in the scaled mode, they will contain 2x assets.